# Как узнать через jQuery, что поле находится не в фокусе?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как узнать через jQuery, что поле находится не в фокусе?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`.is( ":focus" )`](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/)

Comment: Странно, но почему-то здесь ничего не говорится об этом селекторе:

http://jquery-docs.ru/Selectors/

Интересно, почему....

Comment: Потому что документацию лучше всегда смотреть на оффсайте, [на котором этот селектор описан](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Да уж...согласен)

Comment: И еще, вероятно, потому, что "jQuery(':focus')   version added: 1.6". А ваш перевод видимо к 1.5-

Comment: У меня вот эта версия стоит:

http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js

Answer (score 2):

```
var el = $('.my_el');
if (!el.is(":focus")){
     alert('Not focused');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

А на нативе вам разве не пойдет? :

```
<script>
function isFocus(id){
 inpt=document.getElementById(id);
 //Если функция вызвана значит поле в фокусе
 //Можно убрать фокус так: inpt.blur();
 //Можно фокусировать браузер на инпуте так: inpt.focus(); 
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="fortextinput" onFocus="isFocus('fortextinput')" value="">
```

Comment: Какая-то фигня. Извини, что весьма грубовато...

Да, и кстати, метод **focus()** устанавливает фокус ввода, а не проверяет его =)

Answer (score -1):

Можно поступить по-хитрому: назначить всем DOM-элементам страницы обработчик `"onfocus"`(с помощью jQuery, разумеется) и если таковое сработало, то обновляем ссылку на объект, где сработал назначенный нами метод:

```
<div id="mydiv"> !Сюда мы будем выводить тип объекта из таймера! </div>

<script>
focused_object = 0;  // ссылка на объект, обладающий фокусом ввода

$("*").focus(function(){focused_object = this;}) // назначаем обработчик

function pmsg()
{
$("#mydiv").empty();
$("#mydiv").append("<span color='red'>"+focused_object+"</span>");
}
window.setInterval("pmsg()",1); // проверяем...

</script>
```

Comment: Я бы назвал это не хитростью а убийством машины клиента...
Первый вариант самый адекватный